# Is ReadAsArray in gdal-python the same as GDALRasterIO in C-GDAL?

Tags: python, c, arrays, gdal

Hi I am trying to iterate over the values of a raster dataset (band1). I am able to do it in python with the following code snippet (*sorry I can't provide the original raster*)

```
import numpy as np
import gdal 

path = "data/Isle_wight.tif"

ds = gdal.Open(path)
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
print(myarray.shape[0])
#print(columns)
for j in range(myarray.shape[0]-1):
    for i in range(myarray.shape[1]-1):
        print( myarray[j][i])
```

My goal is to emulate the same in C-GDAL,

here is my code snippet (*which does not work*)

```
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h"
int main()
{

    GDALDatasetH raster;
    GDALAllRegister();
    raster = GDALOpen( "/home/roger/Documents/98_GDAL_C++_snippets/data/Isle_wight.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if(raster==NULL)
    {
    printf("Invalid Raster Dataset");
    }
    else
    {
    GDALRasterBandH raster_band;
    int XSize, YSize;

    raster_band = GDALGetRasterBand( raster, 1);
    GDALGetBlockSize( raster_band, &XSize, &YSize);
    float *pafScanline;
    int nXSize = GDALGetRasterBandXSize (raster_band);
    int nYSize = GDALGetRasterBandYSize (raster_band);
    pafScanline = (float*) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nXSize);
    int address_of_pafScanline = *pafScanline;
    int band1[nXSize][nYSize];
    int band1 = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0,GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i <= nXSize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < nYSize; j++ ) {
            printf("%d", band1[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Question: What does GDALRasterIO returns?, I did an array declaration when writing in line 25:

```
int band1[nXSize][nYSize],
```

And then I read the raster Data and assign it to the previous band1 array in the following line (26):

```
int band1 = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0,GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
```

When compiling through

```
cc open_array.c -o open_array -lgdal
```

I got the following error:

```
open_array.c: In function ‘main’:
open_array.c:26:9: error: conflicting types for ‘band1’
     int band1 = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0,GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
         ^~~~~
open_array.c:25:9: note: previous declaration of ‘band1’ was here
     int band1[nXSize][nYSize];
         ^~~~~
open_array.c:29:31: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
             printf("%d", band1[i][j]);
```

Why does that happen?
Should I get rid of the declaration in line 25?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does GDALRasterIO returns?

As per [documentation](https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#gdal_8h_1afb94984e55f110ec5346fc7ab6a139ef) it returns a [CPLErr](https://gdal.org/api/cpl.html#_CPPv46CPLErr) which is an `int` value. You may use this value in order to check if your read was successful or not:

```
CPLErr readResult = GDALRasterIO(raster_band, 0, 0,GF_Read, nXSize, 1, pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
if (readResult != CE_None) {
  // error reading the file
}
// else continue processing
```

The error that you have in your code is related to the fact that you're trying to redeclare the same variable (`band1`) twice. That's what the complier complains about.
You have first `int band1[nXSize][nYSize]` -> declaring the variable once and then after you have `int band1 = GDALRasterIO(...`. Since you're using the type (`int`) again you redeclare the variable. If you don't want to redeclare it you should do only an assignment on the second line: `band1 = GDALRasterIO(...`. Anyways the type of `band1` is not right, it shouldn't be a matrix.